# Using null for super parameter

Tags: java

If an abstract superclass has a constructor which only defines initial field parameters, and one of the subclasses does not use one of the field parameters in its initialization, can I simply put a "null" where the unused field argument goes in the super() call?

To illustrate this more clearly, here's an example:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    protected int xPos;
    protected int yPos;
    protected int zPos; 

    public SuperClass(int xPos, int yPos, int zPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.zPos = zPos;
    }
    ... getters & setters, etc.
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public SubClass(int xPos, int yPos) {
        super(xPos, yPos, null);
    }
}
```

Is this acceptable? Is this good coding practice? Or is it better to have multiple constructors to accept the different types of arguments?

Comment: You will get compile error before talking about coding practice. Just set it to some ***sensible*** default value.

Comment: Can't set an int to `null`....

Comment: if it compilers it's acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign `null` to int type.

I would recommend to have several constructors. This way you can control 'uninitialized' parameter inside the class which will simplify maintanance and readability

Answer (score 3):

Because this is a primitive (`int`), you cannot set it to `null`.

Also, it's a general bad design "smell" to have to do something like this. If the subclass doesn't require some of the functionality of the superclass, there's a good chance that the hierarchy is reversed here. A subclass should really be everything its parent is and more.

It seems likely that the subclass should really be the superclass and vice-versa, at least in the example you list.

Comment: Would it perhaps be better if I didn't define a constructor for the superclass, and define a constructor for the subclass without calling super()? Is this good design?

Comment: It seems more like the two classes are flipped, if anything. The superclass should be the subclass and vice-versa. But in general inheritance can buy you a lot of pain if you don't really need it; maybe you should ask whether you just need two unconnected classes.

Answer (score 0):

If it is primitive type then set to `ZERO`. You can't set to `null`